# Issue selecting frame in webpage with Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, weblogic12c

I'm automating some tests in WebLogic, using Ruby, Selenium and WebDriver and haven't been able to select the frame on my page.

Page code (more content is in the frame itself):

```
<html dir="ltr" lang style="visibility: visible;">
  <head>...</head>
  <frameset title="Application Content">
    <frame name="main" src="cisMain.jsp?language=ENG" scrolling="no" title="Main Frame">...</frame>
    <noframes>
    Browser not supported
    </noframes>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.get "http://myserver:7001/CCBNATV/loginPage.jsp"

#log in code truncated

puts "Switch to default Content"
element = driver.switch_to.default_content

puts "Switch to main frame"
myframe = driver.find_element(:name, 'main')
```

I have also tried locating the frame with XPath:

```
driver.find_element :xpath, "/html/frameset[@title='Application Content']/frame[@name='main']"

driver.find_element :xpath, "/frame[@name='main']"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kind of depends on what you mean by "select the frame." If you want to interact with elements inside of an iframe, you must first switch to that frame. You can switch back to the top level browsing context using `switch_to.default_content` like you have in your example.

I expect this is what you are looking for:

```
myframe = driver.find_element(name: 'main')
driver.switch_to.frame(myframe)
```

You can also pass in the numerical index for the frame as Shaw demonstrated, but if you have a unique way to reference it, then I recommend passing in the element itself.

Comment: I need to update my question, but I actually have multiple nested frames and iframes on the page. Is there any way to inspect or validate which frame I've switched to? Like "myframe.name"?

Comment: No, you just have to keep track of where you are inside your nest. You also have the ability to switch to the parent frame, which is often helpful when dealing with unfortunately nested frames: `driver.switch_to.parent_frame`

Comment: You might consider using Watir, which has a very convenient API for dealing with nested frames.

Answer (score 0):

the main idea is that you need to switch to your desired frame before you do anything present inside the frame. I have implemented this in java since I have never worked with ruby but it should give you an idea. My code is:

```
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp");

        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='topnav']/div[1]/div[1]/a[4]")).click();
```

Do note that inside my code, `frame(0)` refers to the first frame available on the webpage